# Use NLog or roll our own?

Tags: logging, nlog

Our team would like to use NLog for our logging needs - it does everything we want and is easy to setup and use. A colleague of mine has raised some concerns he has for using third-party open source tools in a commercial environment.

His preference is that we write our own logging tool rather than use Nlog (or any other logging tool). His worry is that we end up using a tool that has no support, or we can't get the source code and change ourselves if we experience a problem.

Can someone help me out by giving some pointers - pros and cons - for using NLog vs. writing our own logging tool?

Our argument is that NLog already supports features such as archiving, which we would need to write from scratch (I am not looking forward to that!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open source has attributes that can make its 'support' superior to commercial. The fact that the source is available to use and modify if the author/project does not support it is the ultimate fall back. If a commercial product goes belly-up you do not have the source code and can do nothing. If the commercial organisation does not provide adequate support you can do nothing. With open source you can fix the problem.

Also an open source project can get the support of a community while a commercial product cannot.

So an absolute does not exist here. In both cases it depends on the company/project.

As for NLog, I have used it for several years in multiple companies and always found the author helpful. It is a project with open source actively supported by a development community. It is very widely used.

There is no reason to roll your own where there is mature widely used open source project available. Why spend anything to get a subset of a mature good supported product were the source code is freely available?

Often open source is safer that commercial.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's the devs feel to be honest - why re-invent the wheel indeed!

Answer (score 3):

No need to reinvent the wheel this time. NLog is licensed under BSD license and thus is safe to use in commercial environments.

At least BSD, MIT, and X11 licensed components can be used. Avoid GPL.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've downloaded the source code for NLog, which does have hundreds of unit tests, which will help in the argument towards it's support.

Comment: One more question - do you know if it's OK for me to make changes to the source code of NLog, build a new version, and then deploy that version to our clients?

Comment: You'll need to consult a lawyer to be 100% sure, but [a plain reading of the BSD license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses) makes it pretty clear that you can simply distribute the (modified) code as long as you keep the license notice & copyright information in tact.  You'll need to check the specific BSD license that they're using.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a classic case of the [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) syndrome. Look up articles on this [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) to find arguments against your dinosaur colleague.

Then go for [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). Also, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84189/preferred-logging-infrastructure-for-net).

Comment: Your `this` link is dead, and I can't find the article anymore through searching!